# XAMPP WordPress PHP VSCode Xdebug no locals

Tags: php, wordpress, visual-studio-code, xampp, xdebug

I use WordPress with a local XAMPP server.

To debug my PHP code I use Xdebug and Visual Studio Code, but it  doesn't work as I expect. When I stop the execution on line 191 and step over to line 194 I want to see the values of my two local variables `$html` and `$rmcounter` in the upper left corner at `VARIABLES->Locals` but there is nothing.

[image: visual-studio-code in debug mode]

When I proceed with step over until I leave my `rm_deug_test()` function I see `shortcodes.php` and then everything works. I see the Locals in the upper left corner and I can hover over e.g. `$tag` and I see the value of this variable.

[image: it works with another function]

What should I do to see the values of the variables of my `rm_debug_test()` function?

Answer (score 0):

In the meantime I found a solution that could be of interest to other programmers using wordpress xampp xdebug php and visual-studio-code: I changed the php.ini file in the folder xampp/php. I had only to disable opcache. I changed opcache.enable=1 to opcache.enable=0. Now debugging with visual-studio-code shows all local variables as soon as they are created when I assign a value.

Comment: This site is more for questions about programming languages than about how different text editors or IDEs work, so don't be surprised if you don't get an answer immediately. You might have more luck with the forums or FAQs for Visual Studio